# bootstrap font color does not change and the navbar button responsive does not work as desired

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am newbie with frontend and my professor said that maybe Bootstrap is good to practice so I tried to code a very simple page, but I met some problem.

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/project1
```

Here is my problem 1's picture (sorry because the picture is too large so I must upload it to this page)

https://imgur.com/a/osfbQl5

As you can see in my code, in my style.css file I wrote this code

```
body {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
}
```

So I thought that all the text must be white ? But you can see in the picture, the text are not white ?

And my second problem is, in this picture

[image: problem 2]

The icon at the upper right corner, it does not work as the responsive icon, I mean when I click to it, it did not show anything.

Could you please give me some advices? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` should be before `Popper` and `Bootstrap JS` like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also, if you want to override Bootstrap CSS add `!important`.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use your CSS, you must store it under the bootstrap link. To fix the issue where the menu icon isn't working, you must also save the JS bootstrap link under jQuery and pooper.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<title>Bootstrap Theme</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

and Bootstrap js

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```